# Change parent container in angularjs with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two separate containers, in one of them I have button. After clicking on it, this button must append to the second container. I understand how to make it in Jquery way:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.drag', function(){
    if($(this).parent('#dragplace').length)
    {
        $(this).appendTo('#dropplace');

    }
    else if($(this).parent('#dropplace').length)
    {
        $(this).appendTo('#dragplace');
    }
 });
```

But maybe angularjs have his own way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can add one custom directive to the button. In the link function of the directive, you can bind events. you can use the same set of jquery codes there.

insted of '$(this)' you can use $(element).  // element is the argument to the link function